# I want to write a specified file on my phone to a tar package

Tags: android, linux, busybox

I first use the following command to get the path to the specified file

```
./busybox find /sdcard/ -type f | grep -e imgcache -e gallery3d -e image | ./busybox xargs
```

I use the command below to write the specified file found into the tar package.

```
./busybox find /sdcard/ -type f | grep -e imgcache -e gallery3d -e image | ./busybox xargs ./busybox tar c >a.tar
```

After using the above command to write the specified file to the tar package, only some files in the .tar are found and the rest of the files are not written.

What causes this? Could it be because there are too many files?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because some of the files have spaces and other special characters in their names. Normally xargs reads arguments delimited by spaces. So try to use `-print0` flag for `find` command, `-z` flag for `grep` and `-0` flag for `xargs` command to force them to use NUL (\0) character as a delimiter.

```
./busybox find /sdcard/ -type f -print0 | grep -z -e imgcache -e gallery3d -e image | ./busybox xargs -0
```

and

```
./busybox find /sdcard/ -type f -print0 | grep -z -e imgcache -e gallery3d -e image | ./busybox xargs -0 ./busybox tar c >a.tar
```